# Compose Lazy grid cells to have equal size

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a LazyVerticalGrid with two columns, What I want is to make all my items to have the same size. The widths of all the items take the same size which is good but I cannot make the height of the items to be the same (take all the available height). Here is my code.

```
 LazyVerticalGrid(
    columns = GridCells.Fixed(2),
    modifier = modifier,
    contentPadding = PaddingValues(dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.margin_large)),
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.margin_medium)),
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.margin_large))
) {
    items(days,
        key = { day -> day.startDate }) { day ->
                DayItem(
                    day = day,
                    modifier = Modifier,
                    onClicked = { onItemClicked(day.startDate) }
                )

    }
}

    @Composable
fun DayItem(
    day: Day, modifier: Modifier = Modifier, onClicked: () -> Unit = {}
) {
    ElevatedCard(
        onClick = onClicked, modifier = modifier
    ) {
        if (day.actions.isEmpty())
            NewDayComponent()
        else
            Column(
                modifier = modifier.padding(dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.margin_large)),
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.margin_medium))
            ) {
                day.feelingDuration.keys.toList().forEach { item ->
                    Row(
                        modifier = Modifier,
                        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.margin_small))
                    ) {
                        Box(
                            modifier = modifier
                                .size(
                                    dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.icon_width),
                                    dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.icon_height)
                                )
                                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.margin_small)))
                                .background(FeelingTypeColors[item] ?: Color.Gray)
                        )
                        Text(
                            text = day.getTypeDurationLabel(LocalContext.current, item)
                        )
                    }

                }
            }
    }
}

@Composable
fun NewDayComponent(modifier: Modifier = Modifier, onClicked: () -> Unit = {}) {
        Box(modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize()
            .clickable { onClicked() }
            .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary)) {
            Image(
                imageVector = Icons.Filled.Add,
                contentDescription = "Add Actions",
                modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center)
            )
        }
}
```

So the NewDayComponent needs to take the same max height which it does not. I tried setting IntrinsicHeight to the Card but it did not fix the issue.